# AngularJS - ngOptions: How to order by Group Name and then by Label

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, ng-options, angularjs-orderby

Let's assume I have the following data array in this form:

```
var data = [{group:GroupA, label: BB}, {group:GroupB, label: DD}.....].
```

My binding would be something like:

```
<select data-ng-options="c as c.label group by c.group for c in data"></select>
```

I would like the dropdown to list all the items with `GroupA` before `GroupB` while having them also sorted under each group.

Something like this:

```
GroupA
AA
BB
CC

GroupB
DD
EE
FF
```

I know I can use the `orderBy` Angular filter, but that doesn't really work the way I need. My guess is I have to write a custom filter that manually orders the list the way I want, but I was wondering if there is an easier way to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`orderBy` can take an array of multiple parameters to order by. So you can do:

```
c as c.label group by c.group for c in data | orderBy:['group','label']
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/UWfbr/)

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize you can pass in an array to the orderBy. Guess I overlook that part in the angularjs documentation. But at least I knew there were be an easier way since that would be a pretty common use case.

Comment: could you specify a sort order using this method? i.e. I want to sort by group asc then label desc?

Comment: @RossJones Yes, you would change `['group','label']` to `['+group','-label']`

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `orderBy` would work exactly like you want.

Just take your expression and add the orderBy at the end:

```
c as c.label group by c.group for c in data | orderBy:'label'
```

This will first order the `data` array by the value of each item's `label` property, and then group them. Because the data will have been ordered correctly, each group will show up sorted correctly.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QhNf7/)

Note how the initial array is defined in backwards order, but is sorted correctly in each group in the select.

Comment: that actually would not guarantee Group A before Group B. if you have Group A to contain only "GG, HH, II", the order would be reversed. I guess i gave a bad example case. :P. I was actually able to get this to work by sorting by Group first and if the two groups are the same, then sort it by label value.